# Version of dart used in my existing project

Tags: dart, flutter, angular-dart

I have a flutter project. I want to know what version of dart language is used in development of the project. And i also want to know the version of flutter framework which is used for developing the project.
Is there any way to know these details?
I do not have documentation of the project.

I tried flutter doctor command but it gives current version of dart and flutter framework installed in my android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `pubspec.yaml`, you will find the following

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

this indicates that this project works with dart 2.1.0 and above

learn more [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#sdk-constraints) if you like